# Yourkit java profiler : Cannot launch: it's impossible to automatically detect whether a 32-bit or a 64-bit JVM will be used

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, yourkit

I am trying to use Yourkit profiler for a Spring-MVC based application running on top of tomcat. I am using Intellij Idea 13. I have successfully installed the plugin as well, that's why I could see the profile option, but I am getting the following error :

```
Error running Apache runtime
            Cannot launch: it's impossible to automatically detect whether a 32-bit or a 64-bit JVM will be used
            in order to supply appropriate profiler agent version.
            To solve the problem, explicitly choose the JVM kind in the YourKit plugin configuration settings.
```

Can anyone tell me where exactly is this YourKit plugin configuration settings? I presume there must be some location in IDE where plugins can be configured. Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Check your run/debug configuration setting when you try to run the profiler from idea.

in the `Startup/Connection` tab, there should be another tab to choose which jre to use. something similar like this

[image]

Comment: I just checked, there is no such thing : Here is the screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/kd7joy5gn/

Comment: can you try to scroll down in the selection box (below `debug` there should be another option such as `Profile`) ?